# How can i add an HTTP header in my app on App Engine?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, http-headers, hsts

I have an Angular app running on App Engine and for security reasons i need to add some headers to server responses, for example the HSTS header. Checking on the App Engine documentation i found that apparently you can do it by adding the following lines in your app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    X-Foo-Header: foo
    X-Bar-Header: bar value
    vary: Accept-Encoding
  # ...
```

However, this is not adding headers to my response after adding those lines to my app.yaml file.

[image]

Can you help me to find out what am i doing wrong? I am new on App Engine Configurations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That part of `app.yaml` is only for static files.  For non-static files, you need to set the headers in your own server code.

Comment: @gaefan for example, if your server is Apache you can add headers with a simple HTAccess file but if my app is developed with Angular, what is the server that most be configured? Thats what i dont get it